# Loop through an object of arrays that contains objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way that lets me loop through an object of arrays that contains objects?

I think it looks weird. Let me give you an example:

```
data {
  monday = [
    {from:"55:00", to:"12:00", txt: "hello"},
    {from:"55:00", to:"12:00", txt: "study"},
    {from:"55:00", to:"12:00", txt: "play"}
  ],
  tuesday = [
    {from:"7:00", to:"11:00", txt: "watch"},
    {from:"09:00", to:"13:00", txt: "swim"},
  ]
}
```

Let's suppose that the user picks a day from a select option and that day will decide in which array of the data object the data that the user will input will be saved.

Is there a way that lets me prevent duplicated objects from being saved in the data object arrays?

I don't know why I feel it's not clear yet but here is another example: If the user picks the `monday` day, the inputs that he is going to input will be saved in the `monday` array as parameters of an object. I want to know if there is a way that lets me prevent a duplicated object in that array.

That's why I want to loop through them. I googled that issue and I found some solutions like the `for..in` but I don't think they fit my question. Thank you in advance.

Comment: there is no duplicate object in your sample... could you be more explicit ?

Comment: Your example isn't valid JavaScript syntax. But in any case, if you know that the user has selected `monday` then all you have to do is access that property either with `data.monday` or `data['monday']`, or if you have a variable that contains the string you can use that -- `data[yourVariable]`.

Comment: Yes - but instead of using Arrays, use [Sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set).

Comment: @Herohtar that's my problem I don't know what the user select he has the choice to select any day of the week

Comment: Where's the code that handles the user's selection?

Comment: I don't think you understand what I'm trying to say imagine if the user enter the {from:"55:00", to:"12:00", txt: "hello"}, here I don't want it to be added to the data structure

Comment: So what you're actually asking is how to detect duplicates in that data structure and only add something if it is not already there.

Answer (score 1):

The object is invalid, assuming that the object is the following:

```
const data = {
    monday: [
        { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'hello' },
        { from: '09:00', to: '13:00', txt: 'study' },
        { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'play' }
    ],
    tuesday: [
        { from: '7:00', to: '11:00', txt: 'watch' },
        { from: '09:00', to: '13:00', txt: 'swim' }
    ]
};
```

You can try this validation function

```
function hasObject({ day, object }) {
    const dataset = data[day];

    return dataset.some(data => {
        return (
            data.from === object.from &&
            data.to === object.to &&
            data.txt === object.txt
        );
    });
}
```

Using [Array​.prototype​.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

> The some() method tests whether at least one element in the array
>   passes the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a
>   Boolean value.

Please try this example

```js
const data = {
    monday: [
        { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'hello' },
        { from: '09:00', to: '13:00', txt: 'study' },
        { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'play' }
    ],
    tuesday: [
        { from: '7:00', to: '11:00', txt: 'watch' },
        { from: '09:00', to: '13:00', txt: 'swim' }
    ]
};

function hasObject({ day, object }) {
    const dataset = data[day];

    return dataset.some(entry => {
        return (
            entry.from === object.from &&
            entry.to === object.to &&
            entry.txt === object.txt
        );
    });
}

const result = hasObject({
    day: 'monday',
    object: { from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'hello' }
});

console.log(result);
```

The result is true, because the object `{ from: '55:00', to: '12:00', txt: 'hello' }` is in the list of objects of the day.

I hope I have interpreted your case properly

Comment: yeah it works and thank you, I consider myself a newb in Es6 would you please tell me why you puted the day and the object in curly braces in the has object function parameters and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
let data = { monday: [{ from: "55:00", to: "12:00", txt: "hello" }, { from: "09:00", to: "13:00", txt: "study" }, { from: "55:00", to: "12:00", txt: "play" } ], tuesday: [{ from: "7:00", to: "11:00", txt: "watch" }, { from: "09:00", to: "13:00", txt: "swim" }, ] }

let selectedDay = 'monday'
let dubData = { from: "09:00", to: "13:00", txt: "study"}
let cleanData = { from: "19:00", to: "21:00", txt: "FOO"}

let areSame = (o1,o2) => Object.entries(o1).every(([k,v]) => o2[k] === v)
let hasEntry = (arr, obj) => arr.some(x => areSame(obj, x))

console.log(hasEntry(data[selectedDay], dubData))
console.log(hasEntry(data[selectedDay], cleanData))
```

Where you would create a function to compare objects if they are the same (`areSame` function - note this is a **VERY** simplistic comparison based on your use case. This would compare only primitive values etc). Another function `hasEntry` would check if there is a duplicate object in an array.

So you would just get the needed data set `slice` based on the selected day (in this case `monday` - like `data[selectedDay]`) and pass with the new object to the `hasEntry` function for validation.

This utilizes [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some), [Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)